# Custom color not applying to title bar properly on Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I created a `gtk.css` file in the `.config/gtk-4.0` directory of my system. The file has the following contents:

```
headerbar {
  background: #121212;
  border-color: #121212
 }
```

I did this so that the titlebar blended with the background color of my terminal

The problem is that the title bar of the other applications also changes color, however it does not apply to the whole title bar. There is a thin line of grey-sh-ness left at the top.

I have attached an image to this question for further clarification
[image: nautilus]

GNOME Version: 45.1
Windowing System: X11